# PostgreSQL: data retrieving from a many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, many-to-many, relationship

I need some help to retrieve data from a N-M relationship (N projects in M states).
I wrote the following SELECT, no errors but the result is 0 rows (actually there are 6 projects in France)....

```
SELECT
    p.id_prj, p.title
FROM
    table_p p
JOIN
    table_ps ps ON p.id_prj = ps.id_project
JOIN
    table_s s ON s.st_code = ps.id_state
WHERE
    s.name = 'France'
```

Tables are:

- TABLE_P (fields: id_prj, title....)
- TABLE_S (fields: st_code, state....)
- TABLE_PS (fields: id_project, id_state)

Each of the table has the primary key set.
So, what's wrong? What's missing? Any help would be appreciated ;-)

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. Your SQL statement looks good, btw.

Comment: The answer is use `EXISTS(...)`

Comment: BTW 'name <> 'state" Typo?

Comment: @wildplasser it was my error: I've edited the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select only from table_p, and use WHERE EXISTS(...) :

---

```
SELECT *
    -- p.id_prj, p.title
FROM table_p p
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM table_ps ps 
        JOIN table c ON c.st_code = ps.id_state AND c.name = 'France'
        WHERE ps.id_project = p.id_prj 
        );
```

Comment: Same result: 0 rows retrieved

Comment: Maybe there are errors in your data. Such as: upper/lower case, or leading/trailing spaces?

Comment: Yes, thank you @wildplasser. Now it works! There was an error in my data.